# Не могу получить refresh_token

Tags: api, youtube, token

Я работаю с youtube api, при авторизации google присылает временный токен для работы с api. В json'e который присылает google  нету refresh_token'а.

Выставил access_type = offline так, как этого требует google для того, что бы можно было получить refresh_token, но ничего не выходит.

Я пишу приложение в котором постоянная авторизация не приемлема нужно, обновлять access_token на стороне сервера без подтверждения прав на клиенте(браузере).

Вроде всё делаю правильно, но получить refresh_token не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил! Оказывается нужно было задать параметру approval_prompt значение force.

Появляется дополнительное окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вызвать параметр approval_prompt с любым другим параметром то refresh_token'а в json-массиве не будет.